# removing *.o in makefile is not cleaning files

Tags: makefile, vxworks, building, rm

In makefile's `clean` i have written like `rm -rf *.o`. But its not cleaning files. If i have given `rm -rf libdummy.o` then its cleaning it properly. So if I use `*`, its not working as expected.

```
clean:
    rm -rf *.o
    rm -rf dummy.a
```

and the output is

```
    [exec] rm -rf *.o
    [exec] rm -rf dummy.a
```

If the folder is having `a.o`, `b.o` and `dummy.a`. After `make clean`, `a.o` and `b.o` presents in that folder itsefl, `dummy.a` got deleted.

Note : I am executing this make in windows, building for vxworks using tornado 2.2 package. All the commands like make, cd, cp, rm from my makefile is executed from tornado package.
There is no file name called `clean`. More over I have declared `clean` as `PHONY` tag also.

Below discussion is different from my problem.

[Makefile clean not removing *.o files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535618/makefile-clean-not-removing-o-files)

Comment: You should probably post the relevant parts of your makefile

Comment: Post also relevant parts of outputs of your make run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a Unix enviroment, the expansion of wildcards like `*.o` is handled by the shell before invoking other programs like `rm`. If I recall correctly, Tornado does not include a Unix-style shell. I suspect that its `make` instead uses `cmd.exe` to invoke commands. `cmd.exe` doesn't do wildcard expansion like a Unix shell. It would simply pass the `*.o` to `rm`, which would silently ignore it, due to the `-f` option.

If that is the cause of the problem, you could either use the Windows `del` command, which does its own wildcard expansion, or you could let `make` do the wildcard expansion for you by writing `rm -rf $(wildcard *.o)`.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to include the following in you makefile after objects declaration:
all: [your executive names] clean

** just solved my makefile problem, as clean must be explicitly declared.